# Pandas ways to calculate

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, calculation

I read a file with `pandas_read` and the Result is:

```
  TotIrr  DiffIrr   Temp  WindSpeed
0     3.2      2.5  19.67       0.34
1     1.8      0.0  19.67       0.35
2     2.5      1.4  19.67       0.31
3     3.7      2.5  19.67       0.30
4     3.2      2.5  19.67       0.32
```

A simple way to calculate columns is:

```
df['WS * 2'] = df['WindSpeed'] * 2
```

Output:

```
  TotIrr  DiffIrr   Temp  WindSpeed  WS * 2
0     3.2      2.5  19.67       0.34    0.68
1     1.8      0.0  19.67       0.35    0.70
2     2.5      1.4  19.67       0.31    0.62
3     3.7      2.5  19.67       0.30    0.60
4     3.2      2.5  19.67       0.32    0.64
```

How can I calculate say `WindSpeed_index_4` with `Temp_index_2`? Is there a simple way?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're trying to do? Would this be a type of rolling calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone already mentioned this method in the comments, but just to make it clearer, you can use:

```
df['Fourth WindSpeed'] = df['WindSpeed'].shift(-4)
df['Second Temp'] = df['Temp'].shift(-2)
df['Third Value'] = df['Forth WindSpeed'] * df['Second Temp']
```

This would be the general idea to accomplish what you need in pandas. Take note that 'Third Value' column will follow the original index of the df. If you need it to follow some other index, you can use:

```
df['Shift Third Value'] = df['Third Value'].shift(x) # x is an integer
```

Once you get the technique to achieve what you need, you can usually compress the statements to make it more efficient:

```
df['Third Value'] = df['WindSpeed'].shift(-4) * df['Temp'].shift(-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['WindSpeed'].iloc[4] * df['Temp'].iloc[2]
```

Comment: That works, but every value in the new column is the same. Is there a way to take the 4th value of WindSpeed and the 2nd value of Temp and calculate a third value, then proceed to the next row? Like a for loop, only with Pandas.

Comment: What you are saying is not clear. What would the loop do after take the 4th value of WindSpeed and the 2nd value of Temp and calculate a third value?

Comment: I think they're looking for `shift`.